# Angularjs table nth-of-type

Tags: html, css, angularjs, css-selectors

I am trying to change the background colour of a circle that contains the row index number in an angularjs table using nth-of-type

html

```
<table class="section-table">
    <tr ng-repeat="defect in defects">
        <td width="10%"><div class="count-circle">{{$index + 1}}</div></td>
        <td width="40%">{{ defect.name }}</td>
        <td width="10%">
            <i style="color:#00C853" class="far fa-comment fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ defect.defect_count }}
        </td>
        <td width="20%"><span class="pull-right">{{ defect.date }}</span></td>
        <td width="20%"><button class="btn-details pull-right">Details</button>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css

```
.section-table tr td div.count-circle:nth-of-type(5n+1) {
    background-color: blue;
}

.section-table tr td div.count-circle:nth-of-type(5n+2) {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.section-table tr td div.count-circle:nth-of-type(5n+3) {
    background-color: black;
}
```

I can get the tr to change colour and the td but I cannot get the count-circle class to change color, can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are repeating the `tr` so your code should be like this:

```
.section-table tr:nth-of-type(5n+1) td div.count-circle {
    background-color: blue;
}

.section-table tr:nth-of-type(5n+2) td div.count-circle {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.section-table tr:nth-of-type(5n+3) td div.count-circle {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!